# Are models of PFA from different supercompact cardinals distinguishable?

Tags: set-theory

I am not (seeking to become) a professional mathematician, but for arcane reasons I’m more than commonly interested in set theory. So I am reading Jech’s Set Theory, and now find myself wondering about the Proper Forcing Axiom and supercompact cardinals, trying to form a better picture of what’s going on here.

Specifically, I wonder about the following. The proof Jech gives of the Baumgartner Theorem 31.21 shows how using a Laver function, you can create a generic extension on a countable support forcing iteration that “handles all potential forcing notions”. The resulting model collapses everything uncountable below the supercompact cardinal to $\aleph_1$ and the cardinal itself to $\aleph_2$, and satisfies PFA.

Now, I wonder, if you would apply this procedure to two different supercompact cardinals, could the two resultant models then be distinguishable from one another or are they pretty much going to amount to the same thing? Or, could there somehow be a trace in the generic extension of it having been derived from the kth supercompact cardinal, even though all those lower supercompacts have all been mashed into the same $\aleph_1$?

Comment: I suspect the Laver/Woodin theorem on the definability of the ground model gives an affirmative answer (to the title question), but the details aren't clear to me. (Specifically, to drive the obvious argument home I need "any supercompact in a ground of the generic extension is supercompact in $V$," and that's not at all clear to me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give an answer which goes into the opposite direction of Asaf's nice answer. I will steal a bit of notation from there, namely the ground model is $V_0$ and $V_1, V_2$ are two models of $\mathrm{PFA}$ which come from forcing at different supercompact cardinals with the forcing described in Jech's book. It is possible (but not provable) that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are elementary equivalent, i.e. satisfy the same first order sentences.

Suppose that there is an elementary embedding $j\colon V_0\rightarrow V_0$ with critical point $\delta_1$ so that $\delta_1$ is supercompact in $V_0$. Of course, $j(\delta_1)=:\delta_2$ is then supercompact in $V_0$, too.

This situation is consistent assuming (very) large cardinals. For example suppose that there is a limit ordinal $\lambda$ and an elementary embedding $k\colon V_\lambda\rightarrow V_\lambda$. This is the large cardinal axiom known as $I_3$ (funnily enough the $I$ stands for "inconsistent", but most set theorists believe $I_3$ to be consistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}$). One can then show that $V_\lambda\models\mathrm{ZFC}+``\kappa \text{ is supercompact}"$ where $\kappa$ is the critical point of $k$. We could then take $V_0=V_\lambda$ an $j=k$.

Now let $f_1$ be a Laver function for $\delta_1$ in $V_0$. Then $f_2:=j(f_1)$ is a Laver function for $\delta_2$ and $f_2\upharpoonright \delta_1=f_1$. Let $\mathbb P^1$ be the forcing to get $\mathrm{PFA}$ at $\delta_1$ using $f_1$, as constructed in Jech and similarly $\mathbb P^2$ the forcing at $\delta_2$ using $f_2$. Note that $\mathbb P^1=\mathbb P^2_{\delta_1}$, the first $\delta_1$-many steps of the countable support iteration $\mathbb P^2$. Let $G^2$ be $V_0$-generic for $\mathbb P^2$. We have that $G^1:=G^2_{\delta_1}$, the induced generic for the initial segment $\mathbb P^2_{\delta_1}$, is $\mathbb P^1$-generic over $V_0$. So now $V_i:=V[G^i]$ is a model of $\mathrm{PFA}$ for $i=1, 2$. It is now possible to lift $j$, that is find an elementary map $j^+\colon V_1\rightarrow V_2$
so that $j^+\upharpoonright V_0=j$. The reason is that $j(\mathbb P^1)=\mathbb P^2$ and $j[G^1]\subseteq G^2$. The latter holds as the final limit we take in the construction of $\mathbb P^1$ is a direct limit and all initial segments of $\mathbb P^1$ are small, in fact elements of $H_{\delta_0}^{V_0}$, so are not moved by $j$. The first point follows from a similar argument. So $j\upharpoonright \mathbb P^1=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb P^1}$. We can now define $j^+$ as follows: If $x\in V_1$ then $x=\dot x^{G^1}$ for some $\mathbb P^1$-name $\dot x\in V_0$. Now set $j^+(x)=j(\dot x)^{G^2}$. Next, check that $j^+(x)$ does not depend on the choice of $\dot x$ and that $j^+$ is indeed elementary. This is one instance of the lifting lemma.

Clearly $V_1$ and $V_2$ have to be different models, but here we have the next best thing: An elementary map $V_1\rightarrow V_2$. As a consequence, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are elementary equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The question, of course, is what do you mean by "distinguishable". At the end of the day, are we talking about two models being elementary equivalent, or is it something more concrete, e.g. the fact that $\sf PFA$ holds in both? And how did we get the two models, anyway?

In principle, suppose that $\kappa<\delta$ are two supercompact cardinals in $V_0$, let $V_1$ be the model we get with the standard forcing to get $\sf PFA$ by collapsing $\kappa$ to be $\omega_2$.

Now, since this is a forcing of size $\kappa$, $\delta$ is supercomapct in $V_1$. So, we can again force $\sf PFA$ with the standard iteration and obtain $V_2$ where now $\delta$ is $\omega_2$.

But wouldn't you know it? If we start with $V_0$ again, and simply do the standard iteration for $\sf PFA$ up to $\delta$, we just get $V_2$ directly. So, $V_0$ and $V_1$ are two models with a different number of supercompact cardinals, and we can get the same $V_2$ by forcing $\sf PFA$.

On the other hand, comparing $V_1$ and $V_2$ we see that one of them still has $\delta$ as a supercompact and the other one doesn't. And since $V_0$ is an inner model of both of these, if there is no further ground model with a supercompact cardinal, then $V_1$ and $V_2$ can detect this by the ground model definability.

If, however, we obtained $V_0$ by starting with two extendible cardinals and somehow killed off all supercompacts other than those two, then this will be harder to detect, although, again, depending on the specifics it may or may not be simpler.

But at the end of the day, both of these models will satisfy $\sf PFA$ and all of its consequences, which is most of what we are interested in having.